# Inheriting static protected inner class, wrong complaint by javac

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, javac

Consider this code:

**Base.java**

```
package package1;

public class Base<I extends Base.Inner>{
    protected static class Inner{}
}
```

**Derived.java**

```
package package2;

public class Derived extends Base<Derived.Inner>{
    static class Inner extends Base.Inner{}
}
```

The base class compiles without problems. The compilation of the derived class fails, the first error being

```
Derived.java:6: error: Inner has protected access in Base
   public static class Inner extends Base.Inner{}
                                         ^
```

I don't see a mistake in the code. Explain this, please. `JDK 1.8.0_40`

Comment: Your `Derived` class does not extend the `Base` class.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course the derived declaration should read

    "public class Derived extends Base<Derived.Inner>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a javac bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8183183) fixed in version 9.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use `protected` stuff (properties, inner classes, methods) from `Base` inside `Derived` `Derived` class should be either in the same package as `Base` or should extend `Base`

Comment: I'm sorry, mistyped it. Of course the Derived extends the Base, see fixed code.

Comment: @SergeyS. it is a good opportunity to use IS A , HAS A question. Base IS A Base.Inner or Base HAS A Base.Inner?

Comment: `public class Base<I extends Base.Inner>{` the part you need to look

Comment: @HRgiger, I don't understand your point, can you make it more clear?